# What should i do php

Tags: php, html

I think I have an error uon the usertype 3 cause it always go to the notification and if I change both notification and plsvote.php it will just refresh so please help me what to do

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $idno = $_POST['idno'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $position = $_POST['user_type'];


    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE idno = '$idno' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql1) or die();
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);



//if the user is admin
    if ($row['user_type'] == "1"){

        mysql_query("insert into user_log (idno,login_date) values('$username',NOW())")or die(mysql_error());
        $YearNow=Date('Y');
                    header('location:admin/index.php');

    }
    //if the user is student
        else if ($row['user_type'] == "3") {

                $sql_c = "SELECT * FROM users,studentvotes,school_year = users.idno = studentvotes.idno AND studentvotes.syearid =school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow  ";


                $result1 = mysql_query($sql_c) or die(mysql_error());
                while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

                $_SESSION['SESS_COURSE'] = $row2['progid'];       
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $idno;

                //$query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO user_log VALUES('$idno',NOW(), 'Login') ") or die(mysql_error());
                header('location:plsvote.php'); 
            }   
            }

                else{
            header('location:notification.php');
            exit();
            }
    }
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users,studentvotes,school_year = users.idno = studentvotes.idno AND studentvotes.syearid =school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow  `  this might be a wrong query. what you want to achieve with this `school_year = users.idno = studentvotes.idno `

Comment: I want to achieve the syearid, like I have to check if the student was vote at the table studentvotes and have to check the syeair like 2015. If he's idno was their and same syearid then he will go directly to the notification.php if not he will proceed to plsvote.php

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. Please elaborate.